# Touch events in blackberry torch 9810 doesn't works properly

Tags: jquery, blackberry, touch

I have written a mobile application for android. When I test it on Samsung Galaxy SII it works like a charm. Same app when I tried on blackberry Torch2 9810 then it works pathetic.

The Problem is with touch events. I am using JQuery mobile touch events. The move events are not working at all in Torch. When it move my finger very slowly on the phone then it works fine but when I increase the finger movement the move event doesn't works properly.

I want to know that is it the problem with the phone or Jquery mobile or I have written some pathetic code.

Comment: Touch works fine in native apps on the Torch 9810, so this is a problem with Jquery mobile (although your code may be pathetic, too).

Comment: Touchscreen on BlackBerry device is less sensitive than on an Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `event.preventDefault()` for `touchmove` to work correctly. This is required as WebKit fires only one `touchmove` event if the event’s default (scrolling the page) is not prevented.

For more details have a look at [Testing BlackBerry WebKit, or how I encountered a browser tester’s worst nightmare](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/testing_blackbe.html).